# Get values from TempData into view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to get value of TempData into View

**Controller**

```
[NonAction]
    public ActionResult RedirectToMessagePage(string title, string message)
    {
        TempData["SuccessModel"] = new Models.SuccessModel { Title = title, Message = message };

        return RedirectToAction("Result", "Common");
    }
```

**View**

```
if (TempData["SuccessModel"] != null)
        {

            <div id="validationMessages">
                @{
                    var errors =TempData.Values;
                }
                @if (errors != null && errors.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <div style="position:absolute; background:Black; color:White; top:250px; left:550px;">
                        @foreach (var error in errors)
                        {   
                           @error 
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
```

I want to get value of **Message** of **TempData["SuccessModel"]** into view and want to display it.

How can I display it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

under

```
var errors =TempData.Values;
```

you can cast `TempData["SuccessModel"]` and get it's message

```
var message = (TempData["SuccessModel"] as Models.SuccessModel).Message;
```

and use this `message` variable.

Comment: Thank you 
I solve my problem by your suggestion. But one problem is there when I refresh my page this message is displaying. I want to remove this message when I refresh my page. so how can I remove it?

Comment: @Ajay As it's in TempData, it will display only once, if you don't put anything inside again while refreshing (passing again in through your `RedirectToMessagePage` Action). More code, or more precision would be needed to answer better...

Comment: ok. I have one form which contain textboxs and button. When I click on refresh button the value in that text box doesn't get clear. How can I clear that values. Is there any method for clearing values from textboxes?
thank you for reply

Comment: @Ajay : well, Javascript, or a "Clear" method. If it's not related with the TempData problem, it would be easier to ask a new question with example code. I don't see if Refresh button is a button on your own or the navigator's refresh (F5). If it has to do with TempData, I still don't understand (message is in a TextBox ?)

Comment: Ok I will ask this problem in other question

Thank you for your help